# Outlook: Only download mails from the last few weeks

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I'd like Outlook to download the last recent mails. The only setting I can find is the one to enable the Exchange-Cache mode, but I'm worried that this will download my whole mailbox (which is quite big).

Is there anyway I can tell Outlook to only download the mails from the last few weeks, so it performs well (working full online seems to be quite slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not in Cached Mode, then you're not downloading any email to the client computer, you're just seeing it 'live' from the server, which is most likely why it seems slow.

Cached Mode helps this by eliminating the need to go back to the server every time you click on an email (or alike).

When you turn Cache Mode on, it presents a slider that allows you to set a maximum age for the email that's cached (downloaded to the client) to be available offline.

[image]

Comment: Wow.. I didn't notice the setting because I clicked straight on "More Settings". There's another option to enable cache mode, but it doesn't provide any option to set the time range. Thank you alot!

Comment: Is this feature specific to outlook 2013? I've always wanted this feature but cannot find it in outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Only for Gmail with Outlook using Pop3

I think it is good to add, that if you working with Gmail connected with Outlook using POP3. The default behaviour is to download only the latest messages for that day. If you require all your messages, you need to active the parameter Enable Pop for all email in gmail web account>settings.
[image]

If you need more information, please check this link. 
https://www.msoutlook.info/question/583

Once you activate the enable Pop parameter and It will download all the existent emails in you local machine.